# How to create a launch entry in the xface context menu for cinelerra-gg5.1?

Tags: launchpad, context-menu, cinelerra

I've downloaded a cinelerra-gg version 5.1 txz-file from cinelerra-cv.org.
The installation is very easy, no special knowledge needed, so I copied the file  into a folder of my choice and performed `tar xvf cinelerra5.1...` and to run it I have to type `cin` in the terminal inside this folder.

Now, this means, I have to open each time the terminal and go into the folder or I can create a launchfile.

However, in my Xface environment a context menu emerges each time I cklick the right mouse button, where I can navigate by clicking into the programs .

How do I achieve cinerella-gg getting an entry in there?

[image]

This is the context menu, cinelerra-cv is already in there, but cinelerra-cv has been installed with apt-get. Cinelerra-gg however is not there.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your knowledge and comfort, there are different ways:

**Create a desktop icon:**

On an empty place on your desktop, right-click and select "Create Starter". Enter a name and the path to your application, the working directory (will be the directory cinerella-gg is in), and an icon if desired. Save the starter and now you can start the application by (double-)clicking on the icon on the desktop. Maybe this is what you meant with "launchfile".

**Edit the xfce4 menu:**

Open the "Desktop Settings" menu, look for something like "menu editor". Select "Video Production" in the left panel and "Cinelerra-CV" there; this will show you the contents of this application's desktop file. Make a screenshot of these contents or remeber the values. Now Select the "+" in the top bar to add a new starter, and fill in the values you remebered, modifying the name, application path and maybe icon, and select "save starter" in the top bar.

For more information, see [Menu libre](https://smdavis.us/projects/menulibre/)

**Create global desktop application file:**

Ifyou don't want to mess around with your local menu configuration, go to `/usr/share/applications`, find the file named `cinelerra-cv.desktop` (I hope it is named thatway), copy this file to a new one and modify that to reflect your executable path. E.g.:

```
$ cd /usr/share/applications
$ ls cinelerra*
cinelerra-cv.desktop
$ sudo cp cinelerra-cv.desktop cinelerra-gg.desktop
$ sudo nano cinelerra-gg.desktop
```

Instead of `nano` you may use any editor you prefer. Now edit the display name and path, save the file and you're done.